# Can I get ISO/zip for all Windows 7 updates till date

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I've to install and configure Windows 7 on few laptops and PCs. After I need to apply updates and it will download the same updates again and again for all the different laptop/PC. Instead I would like to download it once and install it on all others.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Say hello to [AutoPatcher](http://www.autopatcher.com/). Supporting various OS's and software packages it downloads updates from Microsoft's servers to a local disk such as a USB key and that can be transferred from computer to computer to install the updates.

(and the website supports IE)

EDIT: Not sure about 7 support

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to pre-download the larger updates: Any [Service](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5b33b5a8-5e76-401f-be08-1e1555d4f3d4&displaylang=en) [Packs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a4dd31d5-f907-4406-9012-a5c3199ea2b3&displaylang=en), [Windows Media Player](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/windows-media-player), [DirectX](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04ac064b-00d1-474e-b7b1-442d8712d553&displaylang=en) ([web](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2DA43D38-DB71-4C1B-BC6A-9B6652CD92A3&displaylang=en)), [Internet Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx), .NET [3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7) / [4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7), etc. and have those available on the network/usb/dvd to speed up the installation. Once those are out of the way, I let Windows Update work the magic for the rest of the missing updates. Seems to be about the best of both worlds for me.

For the MS Office 2007/2010 versions, Microsoft has added a folder to the install directory called [Updates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178995(office.12).aspx#BKMK_UpdatesFolder) that you can drop the various [service](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=9EC51594-992C-4165-A997-25DA01F388F5&displaylang=en) [packs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b444bf18-79ea-46c6-8a81-9db49b4ab6e5&displaylang=en) and updates in. While the installer is running, it will automatically include those patches during the install process.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.  You'd have to download all of the individual updates from the website and package them yourself.  If you had a Windows Server running, you would be able to use Windows Server Update Services, but it sounds like you're just building out laptops and desktops not on a network.